# What is the K3D x86 ISA extension?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, instruction-set

The Microsoft MASM language includes a [`.K3D` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-k3d). The docs are sparse:

> Enables assembly of K3D instructions.

Inferring from other directives this seems to be an x86 ISA extension.

I find no instance of the term in the entire Intel Architecture docs. A [Google search on intel.com](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:intel.com%20K3D&filter=0) shows 8 results total with nothing useful. A [Google search on microsoft.com](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:microsoft.com%20K3D) finds only the MASM docs.

**What is the K3D x86 ISA extension? Are there docs available?**

Comment: It's probably the AMD 3DNow! extension.

Comment: Ross is correct, but for a specific external reference to this AMD supplied a [porting guide for 3DNow](http://www.amd-k6.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/22621.pdf) that discusses MASM and changes made to it (years ago) to support the 3D Now extensions via the `.K3D` directive - on page 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.K3D` directive was added to MASM in version 6.13.

From http://www.amd-k6.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/22621.pdf page 8:

To enable MMX instructions, use the .MMX
directive.
To enable 3DNow! instructions, use the .K3D
directive after using the .MMX directive.
It is order dependent.

If I read the AMD docs correctly you need to enable `.MMX` prior to enabling `.K3D`.

The etymology of the term is as follows:
AMD labelled its processors K5, K6, K7 etc.
This aligned with the P5, P6 that Intel used.
Thus the K stands for 'AMD-K' series and the 3D maps to '3D-Now'.

The [Masm release notes for 6.13](http://bytepointer.com/masm/ml613_readme.htm) are just as sparse as the docs:

> ```
>    .K3D Directive in MASM 6.13
>      ---------------------------------------------------------------------
>      The .K3D directive enables assembly of K3D instructions.  Users can
>      check to see that @Version is 613 or higher to tell if the version
>      of MASM being used supports the .K3D directive and K3D instructions.
> ```

Comment: Great answer. Even including etymology which I was mystified by.